# Sharing in Whatsapp Web App?

Tags: web, whatsapp

Is there a way to share a link from a website directly into the web version of whatsapp? (http://web.whatsapp.com) ?I could't find anything about it. Only how it works on mobiles with installed whatsapp app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=textToshare" target="_blank">Share</a>
```

Try the link above